# "I was bought potatoes" is it possible to say so?

Tags: passive-voice

Is it possible in any way, maybe colloquial style, to say:

> "I was bought potatoes"

with the sense that someone bought **me** potatoes.

Or is it completely incorrect with grammar and thus a blatant mistake?

Comment: It would be understood, but this sort of thing would generally be expressed in active voice - "He bought me potatoes".

Comment: I don't think it's particularly unlikely in some contexts: "We went out after work, and I was bought several drinks". Perhaps more likely in that context to be "I got bought several drinks".

Answer (score 1):

Most fluent speakers would be able to work out what you meant, but this isn't a very common usage, and some might get confused.

In almost all contexts it's better to say it the way you explained it:

> Someone bought me potatoes.

(You could also say "somebody".) The exceptions would mostly be poetry.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is fine, and not particularly colloquial. Many native speakers dislike the passive voice, though. One could say "I was treated kindly by my aunt and uncle when I stayed with them. I was allowed to watch TV until late in the evening, and I was bought candy every Saturday".

Answer (score 0):

I was bought potatoes (by someone).

The sentence is understandable, but it's a bit unusual or weird.

It's more idiomatic and common if you say:

Someone bought you potatoes = Someone bought potatoes for you.

The above sentences are in the active voice. If you want to use the passive voice, though less common, you can say:

Potatoes were bought for you by someone.

This sentence in the passive voice is more idiomatic than "I was bought potatoes by someone".

Answer (score 0):

Simply say,

> "Someone bought me potatoes."

Or say,

> "Someone bought potatoes for me."

so you don't sound weird, because such usage is unusual, and, unless you are an advanced English speaker, you might be considered to be speaking blunder!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with either **someone bought me potatoes** or **I was given potatoes** (potentially with details such as *that someone had bought*). You lose the meaning of buying with money, but you retain the meaning of getting it from someone else.